# Small letter in section using classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

In most cases the default classicthesis section style gives no problem. But, there is some sections in which I need to customized the section font style.

For example,
`\section{Fe\textsubscript{oct2} terminated Fe\textsubscript{3}O\textsubscript{4} nanocluster model}`
would make all letter small caps:

[image]

but I want the letter "e" in Fe and "oct2" in subscript written as small letter instead of 
small caps:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to work (assuming `classicthesis`' `pdfspacing` option is active). I don't know if there are places when `classicthesis` uses its `\spacedlowsmallcaps` where the non-robust redefinition would cause troubles...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
% loadad by `classicthesis' already but so we know it's there,
% provides \NoCaseChange:
\usepackage{textcase}

% chemical formulae:
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{chemformula/format=\normalfont}
% better: use lining numbers for the formulae:
% \chemsetup{chemformula/format=\normalfont\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}

% patch \sectionmark, should probably do the same to \chaptermark
% if you're using chapters
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\sectionmark
  {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
  {\unexpanded{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
  {}{}

% the original definition of \spacedlowsmallcaps but not robust:
\renewcommand\spacedlowsmallcaps[1]{\textls[80]{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some Title}
\section{\NoCaseChange{\ch{Fe_{oct2}}} terminated \NoCaseChange{\ch{Fe3O4}} nanocluster model}

% let's see what the header looks like:
\newpage\null\newpage\null

\end{document}
```

The table of contents:

[image]

The heading:

[image]

The header:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Actually when I asked, I didn't think of using normal font, but it looks good too (even better).

Comment: @user26939 You're welcoms. This is how it _should_ look like, IMHO. This way the proportions with regard to the oldstyle numbers and the small caps are as they should be. You might actually want to use `\chemsetup{chemformula/format=\normalfont\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}` so that chemical formulae get lining numbers instead of oldstyle ones.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I use Minion Pro typeface. In this case I should have `\chemsetup{chemformula/format=\normalfont\fontfamily{MinionPro}\selectfont}` instead ?

Comment: I don't have the `MinionPro` package installed but according to the documentation something like `\chemsetup{chemformula/format=\normalfont\figureversion{lining,proportional}}` should work. You might also need to change the redefinition of `\spacedlowsmallcaps` to `\renewcommand\spacedlowsmallcaps[1]{\textssc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}` with Minion Pro.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, for now I experience "Package siunitx Error: Support package expl3 too old" when using chemmacros package, , that I need to use `\textsubscript{}` instead. But that's another issue.

Comment: By the way, using `\textsubscript{}` to replace `\ch{...}` didn't work here. Is that expected ?

Comment: @user26939 you need to update your TeX distribution. `chemmacros` (and some other packages, too) relies on up to date versions of some programming packages.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Stranglely the problem with expl3 is still there even after updating. In my other computer, there is even different error occurs: "LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal." For now, I'll just try to resolve that problem first. If I still get stuck, maybe I'll ask new question about that.

Answer (score 1):

`classicthesis` is printing the heading as lower case small caps already.  So you (a) need to switch off the `\scshape`, easiest done with `\textnormal`, (b) need to reduce the size of the letter, `\scriptsize` is one choice, other sizes could be acheived with `\fontsize{size}{baselineskip}\selectfont`.  For the subscripts an extra `\textnormal` seems fine.  You should also provide an optonial argument to `\section` so these formatting commands don't apply to the table of contents.

*EDIT* If you also have running heads, then you have change `\sectionmark` to include the formatting there.

[image: Sample output]

running head

[image: Sample running head]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[nochapters,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\newcommand{\hdlower}[1]{\textnormal{\scriptsize #1}}
\newcommand{\hdsub}[1]{\textsubscript{\textnormal{#1}}}

\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy text for illustration

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigbreak
\hrule
\bigbreak\noindent
Document Body:

\section[Fe\textsubscript{oct2} terminated
  Fe\textsubscript{3}O\textsubscript{4} nanocluster model]%
  {F\hdlower{e}\hdsub{oct2} terminated 
      F\hdlower{e}\hdsub{3}O\hdsub{4} nanocluster model} 

\sectionmark{F\hdlower{e}\hdsub{oct2} terminated
  F\hdlower{e}\hdsub{3}O\hdsub{4} nanocluster model}

\lipsum[1-10] 
\end{document}
```

The above code provides two commands `\hdlower` and `\hdsub` to enact the above suggestions.

Comment: Thanks! It does the job well except for the header, which is still unaffected.

Comment: I have now added information on how to fix that.