# \emph and \ce in titles with ClassicThesis

Tags: classicthesis, mhchem, emphasis

I have to use the `\emph` command (for a latin word) and the `\ce` command (for chemical formulas and compounds) in titles but the result with ClassicThesis is awful! In particular the `\emph` command in `scrheadings` is all lowercase, while the `\ce` in titles is all uppercase. These is a solution for these problems? I would like to obtain something typographically decent.

Here is a MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,
               a4paper,
               twoside,openright,
%              oneside,openany,
               titlepage,
               headinclude,,footinclude,
               BCOR5mm,
               cleardoublepage=empty,
               tablecaptionabove,
               ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,
            %subfig,
            beramono,
            eulermath,
            pdfspacing,
            listings,
            ]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\emph{Ab initio} study of \ce{In_{0.17}Al_{0.18}N} compounds}

\clearpage

Blablabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: [Small letter in section using classicthesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101411/)

Comment: Simple: the style you're using is not suitable for your needs.

Comment: @egreg I see... An you suggest changing the titles or the style? There is a similar style mor adapted form my needs?

Comment: You could turn off the headers, or make them not use `\spacedlowsmallcaps`, or use short titles without chemical formulas for the headers (and TOC). `\MakeTextLowercase` can, I believe (but can't remember how right now) be told not to lowercase parts of the text.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Do you want to write some kind of answer here? You are the `classicthesis` expert around :-)